# How to instantiate an instance of FormFile in C# without Moq?

Tags: c#, .net-core, iformfile

I want to test a function that attaches files to documents in a RavenDB database with an integration test. For this, I need an instance of `IFormFile`.

Obviously, I can't instantiate from an interface so I tried to instantiate an instance of [`FormFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.internal.formfile?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which inherits from the `IFormFile` interface.

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("placeholder.pdf"))
{
    var file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
    {
        ContentType = "application.pdf"
    };
}
```

But this throws the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile.set_ContentType(String value)
```

When I remove the `ContentType = "application.pdf"` from the code it allows me to instantiate a new instance but without a `ContentType`.

How do I instantiate an instance of `FormFile` with the `ContentType` and without the `Moq` framework?

Comment: "without the Moq-framework" By using another framework? Honestly: why don´t you want to use moq in your unit-test-environment? It´s designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad. Its an integration test. Updated question.

Comment: It is pretty low-level, it wants you to set the Headers property first.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.headerdictionary?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Thanks to Hans his comment, the actual answer is:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("placeholder.pdf"))
{
    var file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
    {
        Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
        ContentType = "application/pdf"
    };
}
```

Comment: I just need to add that the fact that this is the answer, and that ContentType has both Get and Set NullReferenceExceptions makes FormFile a garbage object and pattern.

Comment: i have been searching for this. İt is working, thank you !

Comment: Worked, thanks! Not clear from the exception though

Comment: Not working for me, don't understand why

Comment: Ok, didn't set the Headers property, once set no more Exception

Comment: How can we set a custom size on a formfile?