# Create FormFile from Stream

Tags: c#, iformfile

I want to create a FormFile in my seed function. But I get a null reference exception. Here my code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("testfile.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
FormFile file = new FormFile(fs, 1024, fs.Length, "testfile", "testfile.jpg");
file.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

The null reference occurs when I am trying to set content type. Any Ideas what I am making wrong? Checked before with File.Exists which returns true.

Comment: Have you tried to use a full Path instead of just the filename in the new FileStream?

Answer (score 11):

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("testfile.jpg"))
  {
     FormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
       {
         Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
         ContentType = "image/jpeg"
       };
}
```

Did the jobs. Seems FormFile needs an opened stream.Found the solution here: [How to instantiate an instance of FormFile in C# without Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704805/how-to-instantiate-an-instance-of-formfile-in-c-sharp-without-moq)